# How to debug an odd visual glitch that only appears in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, graphics, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a UI that has some overlapping layers. These are handled fairly simply using z-index and position: fixed. Here's an example of the UI:

[image: Screenshot of UI]

There is a "drawer" type element that has a fixed position and uses a z-index to make it appear as an overlapping layer on the page. Things generally work as expected, except in Chrome where odd visual artifacts can appear, especially evident while resizing the window:

[image: Screenshot of artifacts]

Parts of the page "underneath" the drawer can be seen poking through in a somewhat random pattern. As you resize the window these "cut outs" appear in pretty chaotic arrangements.

The issue also has a flakey nature. Sometimes it will be present and then after a page refresh it won't occur for hours or days (without any code changes). This has made it fairly difficult to hone in on causes or fixes.

I did find that I could trigger it to start again by disabling Chrome's hardware acceleration, relaunching, then turning it on again. Perhaps that is an indication it is related to the GPU?

There are a lot of variables that might be related in this UI (it is a fairly complex web app), and I don't expect anyone to provide an immediate solution, but I'm curious how one might begin to debug an issue like this. I've never seen graphical glitching quite like this before (I'm not even 100% sure how to describe the actual artifacts appearing) and I'm not aware of anything in Chrome's dev tools that can help someone diagnose what appears to be a bug outside the realm of CSS or HTML.